# How to draw multiple vertical lines inside a semi-circle?

Tags: html, css

I need to draw vertical lines inside a semi-circle which is present inside the egg shaped div.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="white">
    <div id="yolk">
    </div>
    <div id="verticalLine1">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #98FDF5;
  position: relative;
}

#white {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
}

#white #yolk {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 130px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 80px;
  border: 0.08em solid black;
  padding-bottom: -50px;
}

#verticalLine1 {
  border-top: 0.08em solid black;
  z-index: 4;
  padding-top: 10%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/qrp1uehx/3/) for my work.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the expected result is supposed to look like and what you have tried on your own?

Comment: Have you tried using <hr> with a rotation ?

Comment: @dtmnn when I add `<hr/>` and rotate the line is disappearing and unable to position inside the semi-circle

Comment: Do you want pure CSS solution? A smart solution could be adding a background-image with vertical lines.

Comment: @Xufox almost looks like Smile of zoo zoo in vodafone ad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a [repeating-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) to do the job. Browser support is not that bad.

[Can i use CSS Repeating Gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients).

You can easily rotate the lines if you wish.

```css
body{
  background-color:#98FDF5;
  position:relative;
}
#white {
  display:block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
}
#white #yolk {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 70px;
  z-index:2;
  top:130px;
  left:20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 80px;
  border:0.08em solid black;
  padding-bottom:-50px;

  background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, white -14px, white 27px, black 27px, black 29px);

}
#verticalLine1 {
  top:100px;
  border: thick solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="white">   
<div id="yolk">

</div>
<div id="verticalLine1">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: almost as i needed,but I want the less no. of lines

Comment: i want 3-4 vertical lines.Background should be white,only lines should be black

Comment: You can easily do that. I have made an edit. Just play around with the `repeating-linear-gradient` you will see it' s pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a start? Simple and browser support down to IE9.

```css
body{
  background-color:#98FDF5;
  position:relative;
}
#white {
 display:block;
 width: 180px;
 height: 240px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
}
#white #yolk {
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index:2;
    top:130px;
    left:20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 80px 80px;
    border:0.08em solid black;
    padding-bottom:-50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.verticalLine1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-width: 0 4px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="white">   
  <div id="yolk">
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
    <div class="verticalLine1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want them to be inside the semi-circle

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest a simple solution

-Add `<hr>` tag to your HTML Code

Give your tag a `class="line"`

In your css class add this

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Then you can margin it where ever you want.

Edited* 
If the `<hr>`  dissapears then try give it a

```
possition: absolute
```